# Serve using your own binary on Cedar, Heroku

Tags: haskell, heroku, cedar

I am trying to run Haskell on Heroku. I have compiled a binary `app` and created a `Procfile` as follows:

```
web: ./app +RTS -N4
```

When I push it to Heroku, it says:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

Now I think, Cedar does not support rolling in your binaries. Is there any way to deploy it?

I have seen https://github.com/mwotton/heroku_haskell_demo. This guy seems to have deployed to Heroku but, it no longer works. Heroku sees the `Gemfile`s and thinks that it is a Ruby app and runs its default Procfile with `Bundle install` which fails obviously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deploy your Haskell app as Node.js.
Cedar stack recognizes an app as Node.js by the existence of a package.json file.
So, you should create a package.conf as follows:

package.json:

```
{ "name": "project-name", "version": "0.0.1", "dependencies": {} }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well. But I don not understand the logic behind it. Can you explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: I think I get it, the key is to deceive Heroku into thinking that it's a Node.js app, right?

Answer (score 3):

I know that you've already solved it, but I had pretty much the same problem with an additional cause, so this might help others:

Make sure to use `heroku create --stack cedar` rather than `heroku create`.

Comment: Yeah, I had to tackle that problem first, which led me to this 'no cedar-supported app problem'.

Comment: Anyway, I'm facing one more problem, I compiled the code using `ghc --make -static app.hs` but it doesn't seem to work. It worked once and I deployed it to http://miku-heroku.herokuapp.com, but it's not working now.