# Is it possible to run my Rails app on Heroku with Ruby 1.9.3? If so, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-1.9.3, cedar

I tried this tip: https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop/pull/14#issuecomment-3192270 .

On deploy I see

```
-----> Using RUBY_VERSION: ruby-1.9.3-p0
```

But my logs show the environment variable is not respected

```
INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
```

Hacky / experimental solutions accepted!

Edit: I am on the cedar stack.

Comment: Have you tried moving to the cedar stack?

Comment: Yup, am on it already, updated question :)

Comment: I currently have a support ticket open in regards to this exact scenario - RUBY_VERSION output 1.9.2 but I'm explicitly requiring 1.9.3. Will post back when I get a response.

Comment: Here's a detailed tutorial that shows how to set up Ruby 1.9.3 on Heroku: [Using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3 on Heroku](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html) It covers deploying an app to Heroku in depth.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's an update for everyone referencing this question... Heroku now allows you to specify your ruby version in your Gemfile, thanks to their addition to the latest version of bundler.

First run:

```
gem install bundler --pre
```

then add ruby '1.9.3' to your Gemfile as such.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'
gem  'rails', '3.2.3'
```

The full release from Heroku with details is at http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/9/multiple_ruby_version_support_on_heroku/

Comment: I've tried this after my app was set up with rails 1.9.1.  Now i'm getting an error at run time which references `/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1` instead of `1.9.3` which is the version i've updated it to.  Thoughts?  Oh, and when I check version with `heroku run "ruby -v"` it returns the expected `ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: Thanks for gettign back, I actually discovered my error was unrelated to the rails version.  It appears that I am infact running 1.9.3 even though my bundled gems are in the `/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1` folder on heroku.  My issue it seems to be is caused by ActiveAdmin (devise) and `sass-rails` and `haml-rails` gems being inside the `:assets` group.  I took them out and it looks like I am working.   So Infact I have no issue with running `1.9.3`, only the gems were stored in the old `1.9.1` labeled folder.

Answer (score 9):

Right, so Ruby 1.9.3 is definitely possibly. As you said hacky/experimental solutions were accepted - this is definitely one of them.

It's actually really simple;

1. Enable [Heroku Labs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile)'s `user_env_compile` feature for your application.
2. Set a heroku config variable to RUBY_VERSION to ruby-1.9.3-p0 (`heroku config:add RUBY_VERSION=ruby-1.9.3-p0`)
3. ENSURE that the heroku PATH config variable has `bin` at the front (`heroku config:add PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`)

When you next deploy you should see your application using 1.9.3 - the deployment output will show this too;

```
-> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using RUBY_VERSION: ruby-1.9.3-p0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc.7
Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
```

Comment: yeah - that was what was catching me out too - heroku support came to the rescue! :)

Comment: shouldn't the PATH contain 1.9.3 instead of 1.9.1?

Comment: nope, even Ruby 1.9.2 reports as 1.9.1 - some kind of ruby 'feature'

Answer (score 5):

Since May 10 it is possible to use Ruby 1.9.3 in an easier way. Just take a look at Heroku's blog:
http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/9/multiple_ruby_version_support_on_heroku/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a Rails 3.2 app running on Ruby 1.9.3-p0 on Heroku cedar today

I followed the steps on 
http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html

ran into a [problem locally with 1.9.3 and openssl](http://www.christopherirish.com/2011/09/02/ruby-1-9-2-segmentation-fault-and-openssl)

but was able to get an app deployed and working
http://mccaffrey-rails32-193.herokuapp.com

no Procfile

thin and pg in Gemfile

I added some debug output so you can see the rails and ruby version info

Its crazy that a basic rails app slug size is 28.9MB!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: Specifying 1.9.3 in my Gemfile, but it was using 1.9.2. This fixed it:

```
heroku config:add PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Heroku Cedar stack definition [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar#supported_languages_and_frameworks) Cedar currently only supports MRI 1.9.2. Have you tried contacting Heroku support? They're generally pretty responsive.

Edit: it's possible to 'fool' the platform sometimes into running some binaries such as [running Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132821/serve-using-your-own-binary-on-cedar-heroku) on Heroku so if you're feeling really dedicated you might be able to package something up. I imagine this isn't too easy with MRI though.